# Why does VueX store retain state across multiple unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, mocha.js, vuex, vue-test-utils

I am writing unit tests for a pagination module, and it has a simple VueX store module.

I am using Vue.js 2.5 and Mocha/Chai/Sinon for tests. Setup is with Vue CLI 3.

The problem is that when the `currentPage` is incremented in the store in one unit test, this state persists into the next test even when I try to create a fresh store.

I have attempted to return a fresh pagination module by using a function that returns an `Object.assign()` fresh copy but this did not work. I have left this in the code as shown in the spec below.

**store/pagination.js**

```
const state = {
  currentPage: 0
}

export const getters = {
  currentPage: state => {
    return state.currentPage
  }
}

export const actions = {

  nextPage ({ commit, state }) {
    commit('setCurrentPage', state.currentPage + 1)
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  setCurrentPage (state, page) {
    state.currentPage = page
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

**Pagination.spec.js**

```
function getPaginationStore () {
  return Object.assign({}, pagination)
}

describe('Paginate.vue', () => {
  let localVue
  let wrapper
  let store

  beforeEach(() => {
    localVue = createLocalVue()
    localVue.use(Vuex)

    store = new Vuex.Store({
      modules: {
        pagination: getPaginationStore()
      }
    })

    wrapper = shallowMount(Pagination, {
      localVue,
      propsData: {
        items: [],
        size: 24
      },
      store
    })
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    store = null
  })

  it('state should be 0', () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.pageNumber).to.equal(0)
    wrapper.vm.$store.dispatch('pagination/nextPage')
    expect(wrapper.vm.pageNumber).to.equal(1)
  })

  it('state should be 0 again but is 1', () => {
    // THIS TEST FAILS. IT IS ACTUALLY 1
    expect(wrapper.vm.pageNumber).to.equal(0)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to use a function for the state in the module rather than a plain old javascript object. Here is my new store state code:

```
export const state = () => {
  return {
    currentPage: 0
  }
}
```

Answer was provided by @SumNeuron from the Vue discord channel.